# CSS transition does not show when there's a background-color

Tags: html, css

I made a modal and it does not do the transition effect when I apply a background-color to my #main div which contains all the content, after removing the background the modal does do the transition effect and disappears slowly.

To ge the modal just click on register on the top navbar.

Live demo for the modal along with the background-color on #main:
http://79.179.201.217/

Live demo for the modal long without the background-color on #main:
http://79.179.201.217/test.php

Just to note that the following under #main causes the issue.
background-color: #eee;

CSS:

```
#main {
    width: 85%;
    max-width: 875px;
    margin: 70px auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 15px;
    z-index: -600;
    background-color: #eee;
}

.modal {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    z-index: -500;
    transition: opacity 0.18s linear, transform 0.18s linear;
    transform: scale(1.4);
    opacity: 0;
}

.modal-close {
    display: block;
    color: #555;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: absolute;
    top: 6px;
    right: 20px;
}

.modal-content {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.modal-container {
    display: table;
    margin: 220px auto;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    background-color: #eee;
    padding: 25px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.modal-container.x2 {
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 200px;
}

.modal-container.x3 {
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 300px;
}

.modal-container.x4 {
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 400px;
}

.modal-container.x5 {
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 500px;
}

.modal-container.x6 {
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 600px;
}

.modal-container.x7 {
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
}

.modal-container.x8 {
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 800px;
}

.modal-header {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #555555;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.modal.modal-visible {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 1000000;
    transform: scale(1.0);
}
```

Comment: They both look identical to me... Chrome 48.0.2564.116 on a Mac.

Comment: Why would the modal be affected by the main div's color? Transitions have to have two states and you only have one.

Comment: they both are working on my chrome 49